# Map implementation in F#

Tags: f#, hash-map

Just as a refresher I put together a simple Map implementation and I would love to get some feedback on it.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type Node<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison> = {
    key : 'a
    value : 'b
    left : option<Node<'a, 'b>>   
    right : option<Node<'a, 'b>>
}

type Map<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison>(root : option<Node<'a, 'b>>) =

    let comparer = LanguagePrimitives.FastGenericComparer<'a>

    let rec add (key : 'a) (value : 'b) (node : Node<'a, 'b>) =
        match comparer.Compare (key, node.key) with
        | r when r < 0 ->
            match node.left with
            | Some n ->
                match comparer.Compare (key, n.key) with
                | r when r > 0 ->
                    let left = Some { 
                        key = key
                        value = value 
                        left = node.left 
                        right = None 
                    }
                    Some { node with left = left }
                | _ ->
                    Some { node with left = add key value n }
            | None ->
                let left = Some { 
                    key = key
                    value = value 
                    left = None 
                    right = None 
                }
                Some { node with left = left }
        | r when r > 0 ->
            match node.right with
            | Some n ->
                match comparer.Compare (key, n.key) with
                | r when r < 0 ->
                    let right = Some { 
                        key = key
                        value = value 
                        left = None 
                        right = node.right 
                    }
                    Some { node with right = right }
                | _ ->
                    Some { node with right = add key value n }
            | None ->
                let right = Some { 
                    key = key
                    value = value 
                    left = None 
                    right = None 
                }
                Some { node with right = right }    
        | _ -> 
            Some { node with value = value }

    let rec find (key : 'a) (node : Node<'a, 'b>) =
        match comparer.Compare (key, node.key) with
        | r when r < 0 ->
            match node.left with
            | Some node -> find key node
            | None -> raise (KeyNotFoundException())
        | r when r > 0 ->
            match node.right with
            | Some node -> find key node
            | None -> raise (KeyNotFoundException())
        | _ -> node.value      

    member x.Item key =
        match root with
        | Some node -> 
            find key node
        | None -> raise (KeyNotFoundException())            

    member x.Add (key : 'a, value : 'b) =
        match root with
        | Some node -> 
            Map (add key value node)
        | None ->
            let node = Some { 
                key = key 
                value = value 
                left = None
                right = None 
            } 
            Map node

    static member Empty = Map<'a, 'b>(None)

    static member FromSeq (s:seq<'a * 'b>) =
        s 
        |> Seq.fold 
            (fun (m:Map<'a, 'b>) (k, v) -> m.Add (k, v)) 
            Map<'a, 'b>.Empty
```

After running some basic tests I found my implementation is comparable to the `FSharpMap`class in performance and sometimes better. Obviously I don't have the time/desire to test this extensively so take that with a grain of salt. I'm wondering if anyone can spot a characteristic of this code that will cause a performance breakdown under certain conditions or for certain types of keys.

**Improved Version**

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type Node<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison> = {
    key : 'a
    value : 'b
    height : int
    left : option<Node<'a, 'b>>   
    right : option<Node<'a, 'b>>
}

type Map<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison>(root : option<Node<'a, 'b>>) =

    let comparer = LanguagePrimitives.FastGenericComparer<'a>    

    let height node =
        match node with
        | Some node -> node.height
        | None -> 0  

    let make key value left right =
        let h = 
            match height left, height right with
            | l, r when l >= r -> l + 1
            | l, r -> r + 1
        Some { 
            key = key; 
            value = value; 
            height = h; 
            left = left; 
            right = right 
        }  

    let balance key value left right =
        match height left, height right with
        | l, r when r > l + 2 ->
            match right with
            | Some rn ->
                match height rn.left with
                | rl when rl <= l + 1 ->
                    let left = make key value left rn.left 
                    make rn.key rn.value left rn.right
                | _ ->
                    match rn.left with
                    | Some rnl ->
                        let left = make key value left rnl.left
                        let right = make rn.key rn.value rnl.right rn.right
                        make rnl.key rnl.value left right
                    | None ->
                        make key value left right
            | None -> 
                make key value left right
        | l, r when l <= r + 2 -> 
            make key value left right
        | l, r ->
            match left with
            | Some ln ->
                match height ln.right with
                | rl when rl <= l + 1 ->
                    let right = make key value ln.right right 
                    make ln.key ln.value ln.left right
                | _ ->
                    match ln.right with
                    | Some lnr ->
                        let left = make ln.key ln.value ln.left lnr.left
                        let right = make key value lnr.right right
                        make lnr.key lnr.value left right
                    | None ->
                        make key value left right
            | None -> 
                make key value left right

    let rec add key value node =
        match comparer.Compare (key, node.key) with
        | r when r < 0 ->
            match node.left with
            | Some n -> 
                balance node.key node.value (add key value n) node.right
            | None ->
                let left = Some { 
                    key = key
                    value = value
                    height = node.height + 1
                    left = None
                    right = None 
                }
                balance node.key node.value left node.right
        | r when r > 0 ->
            match node.right with
            | Some n ->
                balance node.key node.value node.left (add key value n)
            | None ->
                let right = Some { 
                    key = key
                    value = value
                    height = node.height + 1
                    left = None
                    right = None 
                }
                balance node.key node.value node.left right
        | _ -> 
            Some { node with value = value }

    let rec find key node =
        match comparer.Compare (key, node.key) with
        | r when r < 0 ->
            match node.left with
            | Some node -> find key node
            | None -> raise (KeyNotFoundException())
        | r when r > 0 ->
            match node.right with
            | Some node -> find key node
            | None -> raise (KeyNotFoundException())
        | _ -> node.value        

    member x.Item key =
        match root with
        | Some node -> 
            find key node
        | None -> raise (KeyNotFoundException())          

    member x.Add (key, value) =
        match root with
        | Some node -> 
            Map (add key value node)
        | None ->
            let node = Some { 
                key = key 
                value = value 
                height = 1
                left = None
                right = None 
            } 
            Map node

    static member Empty = Map<'a, 'b>(None)

    static member OfSeq (s:seq<'a * 'b>) =
        s 
        |> Seq.fold 
            (fun (m:Map<'a, 'b>) (k, v) -> m.Add (k, v)) 
            Map<'a, 'b>.Empty
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Second revision

Ok, first of all it would really help if you added some comments. I would also suggest giving your variables names which have more than one letter.

In particular it would be a good idea to describe the algorithms being used. In particular you should document what kind of tree and balancing algorithm you're using.

Speaking of: your tree kind of looks like an AVL tree except that in AVL trees the maximum difference between heights is 1, while you allow a difference of 2. Since you never said that you were trying to implement an AVL tree, I'm not sure whether that's intentional or not.

---

Some notes on particular pieces of code:

```
match height left, height right with
| l, r when l >= r -> l + 1
| l, r -> r + 1
```

That's just a cumbersome way to write `max (height left) (height right)`.

---

```
Some {
    key = key
    value = value
    height = node.height + 1
    left = None
    right = None
}
```

This looks like a mistake. If both the subtrees are empty, then clearly the height is 1 and not dependent on `node`.

---

I would also recommend that instead of using `Node option`s you define an actual tree type like this: `type ('a * 'b) tree = Node of ('a, 'b) Node | EmptyTree`. This way you can refer to empty trees as `EmptyTree` rather than `None` and to nodes as `Node {...}` rather than `Some {...}`. Of course that's just cosmetics, but I do think it reads much nicer.

---

#### First revision

One minor style point is that you might want to call your `FromSeq` method `ofSeq` instead as that is what the equivalent function of F#'s `Map` module is called.

---

Regarding performance the most obvious problem is that your tree is not balanced in any way. If you create a map from a sorted list of keys, it will degenerate into a linked list and have much worse performance than F#'s standard map class. Just compare the time it takes to create your map from `Seq.zip [1..500000] [1..500000]` to the time the standard Map needs for the same input.

To address this, you should implement some kind of balancing. For example you may use [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_trees), which is what F#'s standard map uses.

Comment: You were so right about my implementation. I tried adding 50k keys and it exploded with a `StackOverflowException`. After I implemented balancing, my implementation comes out to be oh so slightly faster the the built-in version which I crop up to slightly less object creation and less robust code. Anyway, thanks so much and feel free to comment on my latest version.

Comment: @Chaos: I've edited my answer in response to your revision.

Comment: Damn, you're right. I can't half ass this. I'm gonna tidy things up and drop you a comment sometime next week just in case you are curious.